# Unable to set my custom favicon.ico in Spring Boot 1.3 or 1.2.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, favicon

I started a **fresh new project** a couple of days ago using for the first time **FreeMarker** with **Spring Boot 1.3**. However, I'm struggling to display my own favicon. In fact, **it worked well at the very beginning** of the project but since a couple of days ago, it doesn't and I can't find out why. I already get through the three threads on stackoverflow talking about it but none fixed my issue. I searched on Google but I couldn't find any solution.

## How to reproduce

Trying to get rid of the problem, I've started a new project (Spring 1.2.5 this time) and I got the same issue.
Using Spring Tool Suite : New ► Spring Starter Project ► then I ticked Web and FreeMarker ► Finish.

Once the project ready, I created **HomeController in demo.web package** with one test function returning "home". I've also created a **home.ftl into src/main/resources/templates** and put two files in **src/main/resources/static** : **demo.png** and **favicon.ico** (I also tried to place it under src/main/resources).

The demo.png is showing correctly but **the favicon.ico is not displayed**. Perhaps I'm doing it horribly wrong as I'm a novice in web development.

> HomeController.java

```
package demo.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

> home.ftl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <img src="/demo.png" alt="">
</body>
</html>
```

> pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If you need further information please ask me.
I thank you all in advance for your help.

Best regards,
Stilleur

## Edit

Actually, it looks like Spring Boot overrides every favicon.ico he can found in the resource locations.

Comment: have you set up a resources controller? check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955117/spring-controller-mapping-configuration-and-static-resources and check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234907/right-out-of-the-box-cache-control-header-filter for caching static resources at client's browser

Comment: There is no needs to set it up in Spring Boot as the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration do it for "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/" and "classpath:/public/". Proof is I can display my demo.png

Comment: you can see it at your at browser because you loading it with src url not with href , thus the server knows it is an internal file.Also I am not so sure that you have configured the spring boot correctly as you havent posted your configuration , you can double check it at your browser if you open the network tab , where it shows all the requests on / off the browser , you could check there that you get a 404 for the favicon

Comment: add `spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I'm using the Spring Boot configuration so when I try to get my /favicon.ico it proposes me to download it (the Spring favicon, not mine).

Comment: @M.Deinum I already tried it and I'll retry it but the last time it didn't change anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've just installed the last **STS (3.7.0)** with the last **Spring Boot (1.3.0 M1)**. I did the same things as the "How to reproduce" section of my original question and add the `spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false` to the `application.properties` and **it's working**. One last thing, can you repost your solution using **Post your answer** so I can accept it as the solution. Thank a lot M.Deinum !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @M.Deinum hasn't reposted his comment as an answer, I'll do it.

For Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE, simply add the following line into your `application.properties`:

`spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false`

According to @Stilleur, this has worked since at least Spring Boot 1.3.0.M1.

Answer (score 8):

Please rename your `favicon.ico` to some different `ico` file, e.g. `mycustomfavicon.ico`. Replace correct name in your `href` as well and it will work.